# Error during install of ubuntu. (WUBI 12.04)

Tags: ati, 64-bit, amd-processor

After the check of installation files i get this error:

*An error occurred:
Error executing command*

> > command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe /set {148fbf66-bba8-11e2-88b0-bc5ff42bd53b} device partition=G:
> >     retval=1
> >     stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
> >     The request is not supported.
> >
> > stdout=

For more information, please see the log file:
c:\users\demoon\appdata\local\temp\wubi-13.04-rev279.log

Information about what im using and doing:

HDD info: Using a SIMPLE volume of my 500GB HDD, its a simple due to the boot system is on the 60gig partition with windows 7.
it has 5 partitions total:

New volume (E:) - 55.60 GB NTFS - Healthy
Windows (D:) - 60.07 GB NTFS - Healthy (page file)
New volume (E:) - 252.43 GB NTFS - Healthy - Yes this has the same drive letter as the 55GB volume E, why i dont know.
New Volume (G:) - 97.66 GB NTFS - Healthy - This is where i am trying to install ubuntu on.
Note: I am running windows from my external HDD (volume C:) it has only 100GB used of the 750Gigs.

Sys specs:
AMD Phenon II 4x 3.4GHZ
8GB Ram
Ati radeon 4350 HD
Ati radeon 6750 HD
1x 750GB external HDD
1x 2000GB external HDD
1x 500GB Internal HDD

Ubuntu used: 13.04 (newest according to your site.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04 (in the title there is 12.04, in your question 13.04) since 13.04 the [wubi installer is dropped](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-unlikely-to-be-in-ubuntu-13-04-windows-users-lose-out). However when I made a usb startup disc yesterday I was surprised to see a wubi.exe file on it... I don't know what that is about. I would suggest to install Ubuntu on a separate partition and booting from a installation dvd/usb.

Comment: ubuntu 13.04 yes sorry i was mistaking, and yes it does have the installer, but yesterday i recieved the same error with ubuntu 12.04, and i dont think i have a CD thats rewritable, but i guess i could use my 2gb USB? though i am not sure what program to use to make a LINUX bootable USB, only windows and ios

Comment: @user158537 yes you can use the 2gb USB check [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)